# Django runserver ImportError

Tags: python, django, python-3.4, django-1.9

I'm running Django 1.9 on python 3.4 in a virtualenv. It has been working, but today, it's not.

When I run ./manage.py runserver, I get the following error:

> ```
> (django1)dan@danvb:~/Share/django1/suorganizer$ ./manage.py runserver
> Performing system checks...
>
> System check identified no issues (0 silenced). Unhandled exception in
> thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at
> 0x7f48a01d2c80> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/dan/Share/django1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",
> line 226, in wrapper
>     fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/dan/Share/django1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py",
> line 117, in inner_run
>     self.check_migrations()   File "/home/dan/Share/django1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py",
> line 163, in check_migrations
>     executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])   File "/home/dan/Share/django1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py",
> line 20, in __init__
>     self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)   File "/home/dan/Share/django1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py",
> line 49, in __init__
>     self.build_graph()   File "/home/dan/Share/django1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py",
> line 170, in build_graph
>     self.load_disk()   File "/home/dan/Share/django1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py",
> line 105, in load_disk
>     migration_module = import_module("%s.%s" % (module_name, migration_name))   File
> "/home/dan/Share/django1/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py",
> line 109, in import_module
>     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", 
> line 2254, in _gcd_import   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", 
> line 2237, in _find_and_load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", 
> line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>",
> line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>",
> line 2254, in _gcd_import   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>",
> line 2237, in _find_and_load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>",
> line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked ImportError: No module named 'core.migrations.delete'
> ```

I uninstalled and reinstalled Django==1.9, and get the same error. In lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/, I don't have a migrations directory. I'm not sure what to look for. The command ./manage.py runserver worked for me on this project not so long ago.

Thank you.

Comment: What are the contents of your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

In I have a Django migrations folder, core/migrations/ in which instead of actually deleting a migration module, I renamed it xxx.delete thinking I might want to revert to it. Upon actually deleting that module, my ImportError was resolved.